# Parsing all html sources from hyperlinks in a page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the html sources from all the (specified) hyperlinks in a page.
The page is https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters , the subsequent page sources i am trying to retrieve are https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters , https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Alchemist/Counters ......and so on.

I tried the following code but no result

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('div', class_="mw-category-group")


for c in links:
    b = c.find_all('a')
    for a in b:
        u = a.get('href')
        url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u
        # print("https://dota2.gamepedia.com" + u)
        for sources in url:
            sources = requests.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(sources, "lxml")
            print(sources)

#
# print(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS selector which is easy and faster as well.I have provided couple of print to ensure we are in right way.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Category:Counters').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select(".mw-category-group a"):
    url = "https://dota2.gamepedia.com" +link['href']
    print(url)
    sources = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sources, "lxml")
    print("Page Header of Subsequest page")
    print(soup.select_one("#firstHeading").text)
```

**Output**:
Your output on console would be like this based on print statement.

```
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Abaddon/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Abaddon/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Alchemist/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Alchemist/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Ancient_Apparition/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Ancient Apparition/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Anti-Mage/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Anti-Mage/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Arc_Warden/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Arc Warden/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Axe/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Axe/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bane/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Bane/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Batrider/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Batrider/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Beastmaster/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Beastmaster/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bloodseeker/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Bloodseeker/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bounty_Hunter/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Bounty Hunter/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Brewmaster/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Brewmaster/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Bristleback/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Bristleback/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Broodmother/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Broodmother/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Centaur_Warrunner/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Centaur Warrunner/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Chaos_Knight/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Chaos Knight/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Chen/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Chen/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Clinkz/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Clinkz/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Clockwerk/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Clockwerk/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Crystal_Maiden/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
Crystal Maiden/Counters
https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dark_Seer/Counters
Page Header of Subsequest page
```

And so on...